# Can't login to mysql with new password

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL.

I've created a new user:

```
CREATE USER 'geo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'geo'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

When I open MySQL console window and type in password that I've set window gets closed.

My question is: Why I can not login to MySQL with new password? What do I miss?

Comment: what is the command you are running to launch the mysql client?

Comment: @self, I ener password in Enter Command row when I open console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter to mysql as root and do following:

```
USE mysql;
DELETE FROM user WHERE User='geo';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'geo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'geo'@'127.0.0.1' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Or You can create user that is accessible from any IP (if mysql bind=0.0.0.0 in config, otherwise it will listen local connections):

```
USE mysql;
DELETE FROM user WHERE User='geo';
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'geo'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '12345';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Your issue I think You do create 'geo'@'localhost', but some mysql clients use 127.0.0.1 and others localhost, so for mysql these are different hosts.

Comment: please can you give brief explanation?

Comment: @Michael can You login to mysql console in cmd or terminal with root user?

Comment: so login to mysql console and call each line that I've wrote in answer. It: 1. deletes user geo (cuz I don't know how many users with geo username You've), 2. GRANT also can create user, so at line 3 an 4 it creates user geo that is accessible from localhost.

Comment: Thanks and what here 'geo'@'%'  of the sign %?

Comment: Yes percentage sign